# Glass reflection distortion

Tags: rendering, glass

**Which factors should I look at to make the reflection as neat as that of the reference image?**

Some of the thigs I've tried:

- Increasing roughness, but still have too many distorted reflections and also I can't see the yellow sphere in the cube clearly like the reference image.
- Changing variables on Ray visibility, but nothing seemed to work. Material of the cube is set to default material with : **Specular** 0.5 / **Roughness** 0 / **Transmission** 1 level

Reference

[image]

My Cube  – Bottom and left sides has way too many distortions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Those things at the bottom are reflections (as you mentioned) so care about environment you use.

For distortion you can try to play with **IOR** value.
Another thing to care is curvature of your Cube - more rounded more distortions.

Here White environment with a bit of Beveled edges and IOR 1.15

[image]

[image]