# Making inside of glass

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine

[image]

Both of the yellow spheres are exactly identical, but the one in the glass cube looks more bleached than the right one.

**Which variables should I be looking at to make the color of the left sphere look as vivid as the right one?**

Thank you all always!

Comment: Isn't this due to reflection / refraction of the glass material since the cube's face is not facing the camera?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making glass problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/218735/making-glass-problem)

Comment: for which render engine is this (Eevee/Cycles)?

Comment: IMHO this question is not a duplicate of the 'Making glass problem' question because this one is about the shadow that the glass casts, while the other question is about refraction.

Comment: I was gonna put these 2 questions in 1 post but then I remember admin told me not to put multiple questions at once

Comment: + I was talking about Cycles :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here seems to be environment reflection.
When I use World with simple white color seem to be fine.

[image]
[image]
Doesn't matter if object is solid glass volume or a shell.

Alternatively you can place black Plane behind Camera so there are not lights reflected in front surfaces.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The color of the inner sphere differs from the color of the outer sphere because the glass casts a shadow on the sphere. The light rays also bounce inside of the glass which changes the reflected light and finally the perceived color.

For the Cycles render engine, you can use the *Light Path* info to make the shadow transparent as shown in vklidu's answer.

For Eevee render engine, you can set the *Shadow Mode* to `None` in the material settings.